# not getting notifications of comments

Tags: support, comment, notifications

The last notifications I received (via email) were on 9/12.  There were several comments posted on 9/13 that never came through, and I found out about just by accident.  I would like to attend to anything that is posted.  Is this a temporary glitch or is there something I need to do?

Comment: Ah, Friday the 13th strikes again.

Comment: Is the red dot notification working? If not, perhaps it's the same as [the problem I had here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181000/161783). But I don't have email notifications set up, so I don't know how they usually work.

Comment: got nothing on the 14th either